# Rename Columns of one DataFrame to Another (R or Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, rename

I want to rename the columns from one dataframe into the columns of another, meanwhile creating a completely new dataframe. I am not really sure how to approach this and which is why the consultation. I want to take the name of one element in the string from one column and reuse it to another. This can be either in R or python, doesn't matter too much. The rest of the string values can be fixed values.

Such as:
*Hm106*_120.region001   **1813**        PKSI_GCF**1813**    Streptomyces_sp_*Hm106*
*MBT13*_26.region001    **1813**        PKSI_GCF**1813**    Streptomyces_sp_*MBT13*

Please see the example in the picture posted for better description

Thanks for the help :)[Table Rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Kxm.png)

Comment: it is quite hard to understand what you are looking for. It might help if you provide a data example e.g. in csv-like format so people can copy paste it. In addition to the csv ("what you have") show an expected output ("what you want"). That'll make it easier for people to help you. You might want to take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @FlorianH Thanks for your input, I will try to make the question better stated. I placed an image to show the input of my data and the output that I want, I don't know if it is possible to view and may cause a problem

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.rename(columns={"GCF No": "GCF"}, inplace=True)
df2['GCF'] = 'PKSI_GCF' + df2['GCF'].astype(str)
df1[['BGC','BGC2']] = df1['BGC'].str.split('_',expand=True)
df2['Genome'] = 'Streptomyces_sp_' + df1['BGC'].astype(str)
df2.set_index('GCF', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this out :)